# How to make short caption show up

Tags: captions

I'm using the caption package.

I want to say

```
\caption[My short Caption] {My longer longer caption}
```

and have both show up? How can I do that?

Comment: the short one is for the table of contents and the page head, if you want the main caption to start with that text use `\caption[My short Caption] {My short Caption. My longer longer caption}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Got it thanks! It's a shame it's that way though -- it should be easy enough to set a flag somewhere to include both. Thanks though!

Comment: `\newcommand\mycaption[2]{\caption[#1]{#1. #2}} ... \mycaption{short}{long}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short one is for the table of contents and the page head, if you want the main caption to start with that text use

```
\caption[My short Caption] {My short Caption. My longer longer}
```

If you do this a lot you could define

```
\newcommand\mycaption[2]{\caption[#1]{#1. #2}}
```

Then use

```
 \mycaption{short}{long}
```