# How can I display the Short Title from \caption[Short Title]{Long description} below the Figure?

Tags: floats, labels

I am aware that when using

`\caption[Short Title]{Longer Description}`

Short Title is usually used for the List of Figures. Now I would like it to also be displayed below the figure, and in bold if possible. Is there a simple workaround that I'm overlooking to accomplish this?

The figure label should look something like this:

**Figure 1. Short Title.** Longer Description

Thanks in advance, and best regards

Comment: You could do this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177427/how-to-make-short-caption-show-up Edit: also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91341/display-short-title-and-long-title-both-in-a-caption

Comment: Used the first one, and it is working. Thanks!